# Bootstrap button styling applied to <a> tag won't show in nav bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Total Bootstrap newbie here (and still learning CSS) so big apologies if this is a dumb question...

I had constructed a Bootstrap nav bar with the last link as a button element but then realized it was better practice just to make it an anchor element instead:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="tcsnavbar-links">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Order Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" role="button">Quote Request</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The btn-primary styling no longer shows up now that it's nested in the link element though and I can't seem to write the CSS so that it 'sees' this styling and overrides the default styling on the div:

```
#tcsnavbar-links {
padding-right: 20px;
 }

#tcsnavbar-links ul li a {
color: #5f5f5f;
}

#tcsnavbar-links ul li a:hover {
background-color: #eeeeee;
color: black;
}

.btn-primary {
background-color: #00afec;
border-color: #0296ce;
font-size: 1.1em;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
background-color: #0077c5;
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated, thx :}

Comment: Seems to work for me, but I'm not entirely sure what you may be missing http://www.bootply.com/kuQQ3qN5dq

Comment: the button doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your Problem interesting and started to read the Bootstrap docs and tried some things.

In my understanding it's not good practice to use the anchor element when you want a button. So when you want a button then use the button element.
[Source](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-tags)

But in most cases it works fine and is also intendet to use the button classes on the anchor element. For example you want some Button anywhere on the page that links to the following page like a Next Button.

But not when you use it within `.navbar-nav`. The Docs explictly say

> **Context-specific usage**
>
> Like the standard button classes, .navbar-btn can be used on `<a>` and
>   `<input>` elements. However, neither .navbar-btn nor the standard button
>   classes should be used on  elements within `.navbar-nav.`

[Source](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-buttons)

But what you can do is to use nav-pills for this one element like this. Then you have a buttonlike link in the navbar

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="tcsnavbar-links">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills navbar-right">  
    <li><button href="#" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" type="button">Quote Request</button></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Order Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/jG1TSm46Zx)

Comment: YES! Thank you so much, you were so right... I spent so long fiddling with that and never thought to try pills (and also missed the part about not using the button classes within .navbar-nav)... Thanks a million!!!! :)